# How to create smooth gradient in HTML?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm just practicing code atm. I'm using w3schools and I'm trying to create a gradient background. It came out choppy though. Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #66ff99 0%, #ffff99 100%)
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
  color: white;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color:#7FFFD4;
  color: black;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:20px">
  <h1>Responsive Header</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a green-yellow gradient for the background.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and read [ask]. Do not post spam such as repeated dots to bypass the minimum character filter. Add actual useful details and clarity. Using "creative methods" to bypass filters or account limitations, in general, is forbidden and can have consequences. In the future make sure that your code is a [repro] while paying extra attention to the word  **minimal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CSS considers gradient as an image, it will be repeated initially. You solve this by using the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` property.

[MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #66ff99 0%, #ffff99 100%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;/* new */
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
  color: white;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color:#7FFFD4;
  color: black;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <a href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:20px">
  <h1>Responsive Header</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```